# Load JS script file to Frida CLI

Tags: javascript, command-line-interface, frida

How can I load JS script to Frida CLI (while frida running) ?

I know I can load JS script : `frida -l test.js` But how can I do that if Frida just running and I in Frida CLI ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `%load` command.
[help list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36FeY.png)

```
(while frida-cli is running)

%load script.js
```

Check the `%help` command or the docs: https://frida.re/docs/frida-cli/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).